# My laptop keep freezing randomly

Tags: windows-10, laptop, acer-aspire

My laptop keep freezing randomly without any reason,
What I have tried:

- Cleaned the fan and use a new thermal paste.
- Full format to the whole harddisk with a fresh windows 10.
- I removed the second internal harddisk, and only use one.
- I checked the harddisk for errors or bad partiotion "everything clean"
- I checked the RAM if there is an errors or something but also it's clean.
- I bought one peace of ram instead of two, samsung 8 DDR3 and checked the hrts, everything is correct, but still the same.
- I removed all external devices like USB, mouse, printer, everything, also still the same.

Any idea what is going on with my laptop?
Note: my laptop is only 1 year old, and freez randomly like two - four times a day, sometimes when I'm working, and sometimes even if the laptop just ON.

Comment: Note: By modifying the hardware, you could have introduced more problems. Have you checked the event viewer to see what is happening around the time the freeze happens? Saying it happens "randomly" makes it much hardware to answer you. Instead, please describe the sorts of programs you're running and actions you are carrying out when it freezes. Nothing is truly random, and freezes always have a reason.

Comment: Check for malware. Perhaps your machine has been taken over by coin-miners or spam-senders. Try running another OS from USB drive.